# How to I use sidekiq's perform_at from a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rake, sidekiq, rake-task

I have a rake task, which extends environment, where I call `MyWorker.perform_at ...`

This has no effect from the rake task. It's as if it's a NO-OP.
I have verified that the same code works in the app, and in the Rails console.

I've put logging into my config/initializers/sidekiq.rb file as a sanity-check that it's getting run and doing what I expect.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you ever make progress on this? I've run into the same thing. Super weird.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are not requiring 'sidekiq/testing' or rspec-sidekiq somewhere so your jobs; That changes the way sidekiq runs so that the jobs end up in an array instead of in Redis. Some other rake task might be including something like that, or check your gemfile to make sure those are only included in the `:test` group.